# Use so many Handler with postDelay method in android java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i'm working on kind animation program that i'm showing gif with Glide library but i'm using handlers too much for example showing loader and with another handler sync my sequence of showing others gif , i create like this

```
Handler handler2 = new Handler();
    handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //showing gif file
 }
    }, 1000);

Handler handler1 = new Handler();
    handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
 }
    }, 5000);

Handler handler3 = new Handler();
    handler3.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
 }
    }, 6000);
```

and every one this handler are inside each other not exactly  like above my question is :

Should i only create one instance from handler and use it ? like bloew

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler .postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
 }
    }, 1000);


    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
 }
    }, 5000);

 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
 }
    }, 6000);
```

or i should do smoething else ?
i guess my application lagging a little not too much but i want to know the correct way to do it and if there is better way to handle this i appreciate any suggestion.

Should i destroy each handler and runnable after the task finished or not ?

Thanks in advance